# How to concatenate IIF statements with vbcrlf?

Tags: reporting-services, ssrs-2012, ssrs-expression

How do I get this expression to work in SSRS? I'm trying to get the field value, and if it is blank then to skip it and go to the next one.

Any help is appreciated.

`=IIF(IsNothing(Fields!street1.Value), "", Fields!street1.Value) & vbcrlf & And 
(IIF(IsNothing(Fields!street2.Value), "", Fields!street2.Value) & vbcrlf & And 
(IIF(IsNothing(Fields!street3.Value), "", Fields!street3.Value)))`

---

> **INPUT**:
>
> Street 1: Text 1
>
> Street 2: null
>
> Street 3: Text 2

---

> **Desired OUTPUT:**
>
> Text 1
>
> Text 2

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can put your **VBCRLF** inside your **IIF** statements:

```
=IIF(IsNothing(Fields!street1.Value), "", Fields!street1.Value & vbcrlf) &  
 IIF(IsNothing(Fields!street2.Value), "", Fields!street2.Value & vbcrlf) &  
 IIF(IsNothing(Fields!street3.Value), "", Fields!street3.Value)
```